# Binding properties of an object in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have this Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string forename { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string randomValue { get; set; }
}
```

and this ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person person { get; set; }
    public bool viewSpecificOption { get; set;}
}
```

Then this controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "person, viewSpecificOption")] PersonViewModel viewModel)
{
    //some code here...
}
```

You can see I bind the 'Person', but what if I dont want to include the 'Person.randomValue'

I know I could replace the 'Person' in the viewModel with a string for forename and surname but then I'd have to manually convert it to a actual Person.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this is a neat and secure way?

Comment: have you tried `Bind(Exclude ="properyhere")` ?

Comment: Your editing data, so you should always use a view model. But you can always use `[Bind(Exclude = "person.randomValue")]`

Comment: It seems that the value still gets passed through as if it doesn't work for properties of an object only the entire object, or am I wrong

Comment: [Stop using Bind](https://cpratt.co/stop-using-bind/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke nice article, I think I'll follow the advice given there. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the article @StephenMuecke linked in their comment. I'm satisfied with taking the approach of not using bind and just using specific ViewModels.

But if anyone comes accross this question and has a better way that avoids having to then map the ViewModel to the actual Model, please tell me.

Comment: Using viewmodel is the best approach here. You can use automapper to map them easily.